# Lua hex to decimal, decimal to hex does not produce same results due to overflow

Tags: lua, integer, numbers, hex, lua-table

I was trying to convert a hex value to number but it seems like its not producing correct results as when I am converting the result back to hex. I am not getting same value.

```
outputHash = '317acf63c685455cfaaf1c3255eeefd6ca3c5571'
local someNumber = tonumber(outputHash, 16)
local output = string.format("%x", someNumber)
print(someNumber)
print(output)
```

Output :

```
6192150243476002161
55eeefd6ca3c5571
```

Since it is 160bit, how can I get exact results.

Comment: Lua integers are 64-bit. Your hash is 160-bit. Too big.

Comment: What do you need this long decimal number for?  Maybe your problem may be solved somehow without converting to huge integer number?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff need to generate hashes of incoming request string and then based on the hash value from the hash table get the machine to which I would forward my request to. Basically implementing consistent hashing

Comment: Is 64 bit not enough for consistent hashing?

Comment: Do you want me to use the first 64 bit? or is there any digest method that generates 64bit hash

Comment: `tonumber(outputHash, 16)` returns the last 64 bits of your hash, just use them.

Comment: okay, yeah that would make sense, but lets say I really want to convert this to number, is there no way other than to loop through the characters and convert the same and keep adding it to the string

Comment: So, you want to convert long hexadecimal string to long decimal string?  You should find some library for arbitrary long arithmetic.